# Check if a value in a JSON object from 2 different JSON files are similar and create a list of matching results with python

Tags: python, json, api, python-3.x

I'm trying to minimize the data i would send to an Application from an API but some values are null but can be found in another API, so i thought about making a python script run on a server to add those null results to the original JSON file.

I'm appending the list that has that information stored to the list that matches it in the original JSON file, this can be done by using a unique ID that corresponds to a video game title in both those files. Here's my code:

```
import json


games = open('outputgames.json')
releases = open('outputreleases.json')

games_json = json.load(games)
releases_json = json.load(releases)

# This is where all the results are found in the JSON file
# The results are all stored in a list, so to access the first result 
# we would access it like this: games_json['results'][0] or games_data[0]

games_data = games_json['results']
releases_data = releases_json['results]

#This is where, i iterate through the data to see IF the id in the object 'game' which is found in releases_data 
#is similar to the one in games_data and then storing both matching results in a Dictionary and a list 
#then i just dump the results to a json file.

grouped_data = [dict(data_releases = x, data_games= i ) for x in releases_data for i in games_data if i['id'] == x['game']['id']]

with open('final_results.json', mode = 'w') as f:
    json.dump(grouped_data, f)
```

The initial list in games_data['results'] holds about 480 results while the one in releases_data['results'] holds 470. But for some reason, my code seems to be skipping through some results, I'm supposed to be receiving about 480 results but i'm only getting about 260 results. I'm guessing the iteration i am doing with the "IF" statement here is skipping some ids it already passed, but i'm not sure. If someone can help me make the IF statement not resume from where it left but from the top and actually check if ALL ids match.

If someone can please help me with this issue i am having, or if i am doing something wrong. Any help is nice, Thanks in advance.

Here's a sample of what Grouped_data would return, this is only 1 entry. it returns about 260 when run with the json files, but like i said previously i am supposed to get hundreds more returned :

```
[{"data_games": {"deck": "Tri Force Heroes is a co-op game set in The Legend of Zelda franchise. Three Links must work together to rid the land of Hyrule of evil once more.", "image": {"tiny_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_mini/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg", "medium_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_medium/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg", "thumb_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_avatar/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg", "small_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_small/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg", "screen_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/screen_medium/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg", "icon_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/square_avatar/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg", "super_url": "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/scale_large/8/82063/2778000-tloztfh.jpg"}, "id": 49994}, "data_releases": {"deck": null, "image": null, "platform": {"api_detail_url": "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/platform/3045-138/", "id": 138, "name": "Nintendo 3DS eShop"}, "expected_release_day": 23, "expected_release_month": 10, "game": {"api_detail_url": "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/game/3030-49994/", "id": 49994, "name": "The Legend of Zelda: Tri Force Heroes"}, "expected_release_year": 2015, "id": 142927, "region": {"api_detail_url": "http://www.giantbomb.com/api/region/3075-1/", "id": 1, "name": "United States"}, "expected_release_quarter": null, "name": "The Legend of Zelda: Tri Force Heroes"}}]<
```

Here's an example of 'releases_data' and 'games_data' that wasn't returned in the result but does in fact match IDs :

releases_data:

```
{"deck":null,"game":{"api_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/game\/3030-50627\/","id":50627,"name":"Orion Trail"},"id":144188,"image":null,"name":"Orion Trail","platform":{"api_detail_url":"http:\/\/www.giantbomb.com\/api\/platform\/3045-94\/","id":94,"name":"PC"}}
```

games_data:

```
{"deck":"Orion Trail is a single player choose-your-own-space-adventure.","id":50627,"image":{"icon_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/square_avatar\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg","medium_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/scale_medium\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg","screen_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/screen_medium\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg","small_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/scale_small\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg","super_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/scale_large\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg","thumb_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/scale_avatar\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg","tiny_url":"http:\/\/static.giantbomb.com\/uploads\/square_mini\/29\/291401\/2775039-6490638002-heade.jpg"}}
```

Comment: The list comprehension looks right to me.  Can you given an example of a pair that you expect to be in the `grouped_data` but is not?

Comment: Yes, i've added it to the question. What made me think that it could be a problem with the IF statement is because i also tried associating the different data with names instead of ID in the different lists, but it gave me the same exact results back.

Comment: Thanks, but we're not on the same wavelength yet.  What I'd like to see is  a JSON object from `games_data`, and a JSON object from `releases_data` that you think ought to be paired in `grouped_data` but that are not so paired.  You say you're expecting about 480 results, but you're only getting 260 or so.  Please give us an example of one of the missing 220.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, i posted an example of a result that wasn't getting returned, hard for me to find those since theres allot of data in the files. Is it possible that the IF statement used here ignores passed IDs it passed through to match the one it's looking for ? I'm trying to find some information relating to this question but i'm not finding a clear answer on the web.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: THIS IS INCORRECT. I'm leaving it just as context for the comments.

The problem with the example you posted for releases_data is in the very first field: `"deck":null`  If I try to create a JSON object from this string, I get

```
builtins.NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

There must be some try-catch block somewhere that is ignoring this exception.  You could just define

```
null = None
```

before processing the files, if this is the only problem.  Perhaps you ought to test how many JSON objects you can create from each of the two files, to locate any additional problems, before you go back to merging them.

Just as a debugging tip, this took me perhaps five minutes to analyze, once I got the data to work with from you.  All I did was call `json.loads` on both strings and read the error message.  It always (well, almost always) pays to start at the bottom and work up.  :-)

Comment: Actually, when i try loading the JSON with json.loads it automatically converts 'null' to None, so it means that all the files are basically already converted. Tried with json.load too and it's the same results, nulls are already replaced to "None". I was thinking it was a problem with my iteration because even when i try comparing the "Name" object, it returns the same results. Also, Thank you very much for following up on this issue with me.                   

 
>>> json.loads('{"deck": null}')                    Result: {'deck': None}

Comment: You're right; my face is red.  I don't understand what I did to get the NameError.  When I do exactly what I remember doing before, it works just fine.  Unfortunately, I just typed it into the REPL, so I don't have a script to look at.  I'll keep thinking about it.  I still don't see how it can be a problem with the iteration.  What happens if you make two test files, one with each of the two records from your example?

Comment: I tried the experiment I suggested in the previous comment myself, and it worked fine.  final_results.json contains a one-element list, as expected.  I'm flummoxed.  What I would do is to write a little script to  extract the ids from the two files into two new files, and test the comparison iteration on those new files.  As you said earlier, with all that extra data, it's hard to see what's going on.

Comment: Isolated the IDs, tested them and i still get the same exact results. I'm just assuming the API is very unorganized for now and that they're probably assigning different IDs for the same game(They're not supposed to do that, tho). I'm going to have to use the unmatched IDs and build my own objects myself. One last question tho, can you explain to me the procedure the IF statement in my code runs when it is checking for matching IDs, does re-iterate through all the IDs once it finds a matching one or does it continue from where it left off ? Thank you very much for the help, once again.

Comment: It's just like two nested `for` loops.  It generates every possible combination of a game and a release and checks whether they have the same id.  List comprehensions are typically faster than loops, though.  It doesn't know that there will be at most one matching ID, so once it finds a match, it just keeps going.  It checks the first game against every release; then the second game against every release, and so on.

Comment: Hey i'm not sure if you're still following this post, but after analyzing the Data today, it seems like i'm generating allot of Duplicated data with this if statement, i'm not sure how tho. I just saw this today and apparently all the previous data i had grouped also have duplicated entries. I am trying to isolate the issue but this only happens when i try to iterate over all the Data. Any ideas why this could be happening too ?

Comment: I'm still interested.  Can you put the data somewhere where I can get it?

Comment: Here's the new data: http://sobmad.tk/video_games/video_games.json This is the grouped data. The data i am grouping are Giantbomb.com's /api/releases and /api/games. They limit their requests to 100 Results/request, so i have to change the offset to get all the results. I then extend the first Json List(offset 0) with offset 100, 200, 300 and 400. Also an example of Duplicates in the data, check the list indexes 390 and 389. Allot of other games have been confirmed to be duplicated too.

Comment: I grabbed the file, but your code refers to two files: outputgames.json and outputreleases.json.  Which one is this?  Where is the other one?  Or is the point simply that there are duplicated ID's in the file you posted?  I'll analyze the id's in that file later today; I'm not fully awake yet :-)

Comment: The code on the website is the code i grouped together(Grouping ouputreleases and outputgames). ( I used the For loop) Would you like me to share outputgames.json and outputreleases.json, these are 5 JSON files(for different offsets) for Outputreleases and ouputgames ,on the real code, in total that i .extend() together the results to match the games. Obviously, we would have duplicates because of Region and platforms but some are Exactly the same (Like index number 390 and 389)